# Buzzer keeps buzzing even though the sensor doesn't detect anything

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors, buzzer

through the code that I've listed below, the idea was to have a sensor that detects objects in different ranges, if they're quite close, a light strip will turn on yellow with no buzzer. If they're very close, the light strip will turn red and buzzer will buzz rapidly. However in our case, the buzzer keeps buzzing constantly even though there's no object in the vicinity of the sensor.
Below are our code for the input:

```cpp
#include <Adafruit_NeoPixel.h>

#define TRIGGER_PIN_LEFT 8
#define ECHO_PIN_LEFT 9
#define TRIGGER_PIN_RIGHT 4
#define ECHO_PIN_RIGHT 5
#define NUM_PIXELS 8
#define POTENTIOMETER_PIN A0
#define PIEZO_PIN 10
#define TILT_PIN 6

Adafruit_NeoPixel strip1(NUM_PIXELS, 3, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);
Adafruit_NeoPixel strip2(NUM_PIXELS, 2, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);

void setup() {
  pinMode(TRIGGER_PIN_LEFT, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ECHO_PIN_LEFT, INPUT);
  pinMode(TRIGGER_PIN_RIGHT, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ECHO_PIN_RIGHT, INPUT);
  pinMode(PIEZO_PIN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(TILT_PIN, INPUT);
  strip1.begin();
  strip1.show();
  strip2.begin();
  strip2.show();
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  long duration1, distance1, duration2, distance2;
  int speed = analogRead(POTENTIOMETER_PIN);
  int tilt = digitalRead(TILT_PIN);

  digitalWrite(TRIGGER_PIN_LEFT, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  digitalWrite(TRIGGER_PIN_LEFT, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(TRIGGER_PIN_LEFT, LOW);
  duration1 = pulseIn(ECHO_PIN_LEFT, HIGH);
  distance1 = (duration1/2) / 29.1;

  digitalWrite(TRIGGER_PIN_RIGHT, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  digitalWrite(TRIGGER_PIN_RIGHT, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(TRIGGER_PIN_RIGHT, LOW);
  duration2 = pulseIn(ECHO_PIN_RIGHT, HIGH);
  distance2 = (duration2/2) / 29.1;

  if (distance1 < 200 && distance1 > 50 && tilt == LOW) {
    for(int i=0; i<NUM_PIXELS; i++) {
      strip1.setPixelColor(i, 255, 255, 0);
    }
    strip1.show();
  } else if (distance1 < 200 && distance1 > 50 && tilt == HIGH) {
    for(int i=0; i<NUM_PIXELS; i++) {
      strip1.setPixelColor(i, 255, 0, 0);
    }
    strip1.show();
    tone(PIEZO_PIN, 500);
    delay(100);
    noTone(PIEZO_PIN);
    delay(100);
  } else if (distance1 < 50 && speed > 100) {
    for(int i=0; i<NUM_PIXELS; i++) {
      strip1.setPixelColor(i, 255, 0, 0);
    }
    strip1.show();
    tone(PIEZO_PIN, 500);
    delay(100);
    noTone(PIEZO_PIN);
    delay(500);
  } else {
    for(int i=0; i<NUM_PIXELS; i++) {
      strip1.setPixelColor(i, 0, 0, 0);
    }
    strip1.show();
  }

  if (distance2 < 200 && distance2 > 50 && tilt == LOW) {
    for(int i=0; i<NUM_PIXELS; i++) {
      strip2.setPixelColor(i, 255, 255, 0);
    }
    strip2.show();
  } else if (distance2 < 200 && distance2 > 50&& tilt == HIGH) {
    for(int i=0; i<NUM_PIXELS; i++) {
      strip2.setPixelColor(i, 255, 0, 0);
    }
    strip2.show();
    tone(PIEZO_PIN, 500);
    delay(100);
    noTone(PIEZO_PIN);
    delay(100);
  } else if (distance2 < 50 && speed > 100) {
    for(int i=0; i<NUM_PIXELS; i++) {
      strip2.setPixelColor(i, 255, 0, 0);
    }
    strip2.show();
    tone(PIEZO_PIN, 500);
    delay(100);
    noTone(PIEZO_PIN);
    delay(500);
  } else {
    for(int i=0; i<NUM_PIXELS; i++) {
      strip2.setPixelColor(i, 0, 0, 0);
    }
    strip2.show();
  }
  Serial.print("Tilt=");
  Serial.println(tilt);
}
```

Comment: Put a Serial.print( ) debug statement after each tone() statement so you know which one is being incorrectly executed. Or maybe you already know from the colour of LED display.